# How to remove package using Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Angular 6 has new CLI command `ng add <package>`.

How can I remove the package using Angular CLI?

UPDATE

[documentation](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4)

> `ng add` will use your package manager to download new dependencies and invoke an installation script (implemented as a schematic) which can update your project with configuration changes, add additional dependencies (e.g. polyfills), or scaffold package-specific initialization code

It is not the same `npm install <package>`

I was trying to use `ng rm` but it is not working yet.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can use `npm uninstall <package-name>` will remove it from your package.json file and from node_modules.

If you do `ng help` command, you will see that there is no `ng remove/delete` supported command. So, basically you cannot revert the `ng add` behavior yet.

Comment: Yes i do, ng add will use package manager to run the install script and edit your angular.json file, but npm install will only install the package.

Comment: So you need ng remove command that will edit your configuration again and remove any dependency, css files and javascript files which has included by the ng add command ?

Comment: The `ng help` command show that there is no `ng remove/delete` command.

Comment: Wonder why would some one implement `ng add` and not implement `ng remove`!

Comment: run the install script and **edit your angular.json file** <- This is the problem. npm uninstall is not a perfect solution

Answer (score 8):

It's an open [issue #900](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900) on GitHub, unfortunately at this point of time it looks that in Angular CLI there's nothing like `ng remove/rm/`..., only using `npm uninstall DEPENDENCY` is the current workaround.

Comment: The linked issue refers to component removal. I think it doesn't apply for this question

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a dependency added with `ng add` will add more than one package, typing `npm uninstall lib1 lib2` could be error prone and slow, so just remove the not needed libraries from `package.json` and run `npm i`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about CLI, I had tried, but I couldn't. I deleted using IDE Idea history.

If You use an **Intellij Idea**, just open History changes.

Tap by main folder of the **project -> right click -> local history -> show history**.

**Then** from top to bottom **revert changes.**

[image]

Comment: why do you need to remove BrowserAnimationsModule?

Comment: It's can be added when we connect material. Everybody should try to understand what he is doing. It's not necessary to delete it.

Comment: I understood what u mean, I gave an example of removing angular material, and hadn't wrote about it, I'll delete 2 part my answer so that it is not misleading, thanks.

Comment: My question is not about git usage. I mentioned about git nothing

Answer (score 0):

With the cli I don't know if it's a remove command but you can remove it from package.json and stop using it in your code. If you reinstall the packages you will not have it any more

Answer (score -1):

You can go to **package.json**, and delete package you want.

```
"@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
```

For example, if you want to delete angular/material, just delete that line:

```
"@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
```

And in the terminal, in the root project, you run:

```
npm install
```

This will check package.json and will uninstall the package you remove in package.json file.